# How to bind a text box to a member in data context conditionally?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm not sure if it's possible at all but I wonder if it's possible to bind a text box to two different fields depending on the value of a third.

Suppose we have a carrier that goes from the origin to the destination and has the status of being on the way or having arrived. Because of the business logic and the way my customer works they want the grid of orders to look like this.

```
#Id Orgin Dest. Status
101     A    B   Going
102     C    D   Going
103     A    D   Going
```

However, when the order with ID e.g. 102 reaches a certain status, the point of destination should be viewed in the origin column and the destination column should be empty (or show the next stop or whatever else), like this.

```
#Id Orgin Dest. Status
101     A    B   Going
102     D    -    Done
103     A    D   Going
```

So I would like to bind the column *Origin* to the field *Origin* in my data context if the status is *Going* but I also would like to bind it to the field *Destination* if the status is *Done*.

If it's not possible, how can I approach it? Will I be forced to create a new data type that maps the actual orders to the viewable orders? Or just add a property to the view model that isn't supported by a back field but rather renders its value depending on the status?

Comment: Would be easier to have 2 text boxes and make one or the other visible based on the 3rd field.

Comment: @Mike Not sure if it would. I'm showing the records in a grid view component and each row can be one way or another. Are you suggesting that the I should implement each cell in the two columns to show this-or-that value? That'd work but would it really be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of MultiBinding.

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterNameHere}">
      <Binding Path="Text"/>
      <Binding Path="Text"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Converter sample:

```
public class ConverterName : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
         object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    // Check your binded values and return the string you want to.
    // values is an array of items binded in xaml.
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, 
         object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
  }
}
```

A longer [blog article here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-multi-binding-and-multi-value-conv) offers a discussion on the subject. For the grid view control, the approach is analogue using this schematic adaptation.

```
<DataGridTextColumn>
  <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    <MultiBinding ...>
      ...
    </MultiBinding>
  </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```