# WPF enable buttons group

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In first column i have list of groups ("First","Second"). In second column i have 5 button's. I want to enable or disable group of button's after choosing their group in first column. How to do this in MVVM pattern?

[image]

[image]

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Data();
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    public Data()
    {
        Items = new List<string>();
        Items.Add("First");
        Items.Add("Second");
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Column="0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding .}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="First" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="21,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <Button Content="Second" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="102,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" IsEnabled="True"/>
    <Button Content="First" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="33,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <Button Content="Second" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="126,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" IsEnabled="True" RenderTransformOrigin="1.088,-0.075"/>
    <Button Content="Second" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="93,186,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" IsEnabled="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Bind your `IsEnabled` property and use converter to check for enable or disable based on the selected item.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31885801/2470362

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your `VM` classes like:

```
public class Data:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyRecord> Items
    {
       get{
            return _items;
       }
       set{
            _items=value;
            OnProperyChanged("Items")
        }
    }

    public Data()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<MyRecord>()
        {
                new MyRecord(){Title:"First",IsEnable:false}),
                new MyRecord(){Title:"Second",IsEnable:false})
        };
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnProperyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            var handler= PropertyChanged ;
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class MyRecord:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _title;
    private bool _isEnable;

    public int Title
    {
        get
        {
            return _title;
        }
        set
        {
            _title= value;
            OnProperyChanged("Title")
        }
    }

    public bool IsEnable
    {
        get
        {
            return _isEnable;
        }
        set
        {
            _isEnable= value;
            OnProperyChanged("IsEnable")
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnProperyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            var handler= PropertyChanged ;
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your `Xaml` bind the `IsEnabled` property of each `Button` to appropriate property...

You can write the following code with [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
//First add BooleanToVisibilityConverter to the window resources


// When you know Items[0] is FIRST use some code like this>>
IsEnabled="{Binding Items[0].IsEnable, converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Sample:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Column="0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding .}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="First"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Items[0].IsEnable, converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="21,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76"/>
    <Button Content="Second"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Items[1].IsEnable, converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="102,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76"/>
    <Button Content="First"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Items[0].IsEnable, converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="33,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76"/>
    <Button Content="Second"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Items[1].IsEnable, converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="126,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" RenderTransformOrigin="1.088,-0.075"/>
    <Button Content="Second"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Items[1].IsEnable, converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="93,186,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76"/>
</Grid>
```

OK, every things is good until this step. Now if you make `IsEnable` property of each item to `TRUE`, then the buttons must be `Enabled` And conversely. To perform it you can:

- Write a Command in your Data class and make a binding between each List 
  item and the command.
- Use `ListView.SelectionChanged` event to make `IsEnable` property of the Clicked item to `TRUE`. *Note:* Now, the type of each item in the `ListView` is `MyRecord`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to your problem is to use a `IValueConverter`, in this example I created a convert named `GroupToBooleanConverter` receiving the value of the selected item in the first column by the parameter `value` and the button group by parameter 'parameter ', the code converter is below:

```
public class GroupToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var selectedGroup = value as string;
            var buttonGroup = (string)parameter;

            return buttonGroup.Equals(selectedGroup);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Now in its XAML you must reference the namespace of your turn, in my example the namespace convert is `namespaceOfConverter`, and must be imported to convert through it, is as follows:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:namespaceOfConverter"
```

Place the `attribute` up on your `Window` tag in your XAML. Now you must reference the convert, putting it in the `Window` resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <converters:GroupToBooleanConverter x:Key="GroupToBoolean" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

I called your `ListView` of `lsvGroups`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="lsvGroups" Grid.Column="0">
....
```

Now just use the converter in your buttons, performing `binding` in the property `IsEnabled`:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lsvGroups,Converter={StaticResource GroupToBoolean},ConverterParameter=First}"
```

OBs: In the place of `First` you put the name of group associate with `button`.